# Django angular database integration

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs, postgresql

I have a django project that uses `postgresql`. I am trying to use angular as a front end in my html pages. Which is the best approach to use the angular js controllers in the django project to connect to the django models and the database to perform basic operations like insert, delete, update etc?

Currently i just have static data that i defined in my angular controller. But i would like to know how to get the data from the database dynamically. Any advice will be helpful

Comment: AJAX, JSON, Django ORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my experience with Django and AngularJs, first you should make api in django to get the data from database. Afterthat, in single page application, you should make [angularjs service](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11)  for each api in controller. After rendering data, you can submit / modify your data either through api or through form submission(with [form validation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)).